# F5 key broken on HP Pavillion laptop keyboard, how to access the the keyboard backlit toggle option tied to it through settings or any software?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hp-pavilion, backlight

I have a HP Pavillion Laptop running windows 10 - out of warranty.
So, the F5 key that is broken and it is linked to the toggling keyboard's backlight(its a monochrome white colored light). The repair shop is saying that i need to replace the whole keyboard for the single key
I dont really have a use for the F5 key but i want to turn on my keyboard backlight. IS there a settings or any application.
i know how to change a key's scancode through the registry.. but i dont know how to turn on the keyboard's backlight

Also i wouldnt mind if the backlight stayed always on, so if there is any option like that would appreciate it too.

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Programmable-Keyboard-User-Defined-Customized-Shortcut/dp/B0BR1F9P4B

Comment: Depending on *which* model, a replacement keyboard can be found for US$12 and up.

Answer (score 0):

The only full solution is to replace the keyboard.
Below are some workarounds that might help.

- The HP BIOS might have settings for turning the backlight on or off,
  usually found in the Advanced tab, Built-in Device Options
- If you have an Omen keyboard, use the
  [HP OMEN Command Center](https://www.hp.com/us-en/shop/tech-takes/what-is-hp-omen-command-center)
- You may simulate turning the backlight on and off by changing instead
  the brightness of the backlight using the separate luminance keys,
  located in some models in the top row of FN keys and marked by large
  and smaller flashing light symbols.